# Javascript only working in one section of my html but nowhere else

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this simple javascript function which generates a random image from a folder to the screen. I tested the function and it works.
The problem is when I try to use the function in a different section it doesn't work out of a sudden.
Here are some screen shots

[image]

when i refresh the page the red controller well now be black for example

[image]

but now when i try to implement this function in this corner here

[image]

it just shows the text but no image. I tried to see if it was just that spot, but it seems that once I go below my navbar/header the javascript code doesn't work.

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>INDEX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">





</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="align">Products On Sale!</h1>
        <h2 class="align">Under $20.00</h2>
        <div class="row">


               <div class="col-sale"> <img src="" id="pics">
               <h3 class="align">Controllers!</h3>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>









    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo"><h1>LOGO</h1></div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">About</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
            <a href="">Account</a>
            <a href="">Product</a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/cart.png" height="30" width="30"></a>

        </div>

    </div>

    


    <div class="hero">
          <header class="hero-title">
            <h1>FIND THE PRODUCTS OF YOUR DREAMS!</h1>
              <h1>Happiness guranteed!</h1>
              <button><h1>Shop Now!</h1></button>
          </header>
    </div>


    <div class="products">
       <div class="wrapper">
           <h1>Trending Now!</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-products">
                    <img src="images/categorie-1.jpg">
                    <h1 class="align">PierreBourne</h1>
                    <p class="align">$40.00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-products"><img src="images/categorie-2.jpg">
                    <h1 class="align">DjPremiere</h1>
                    <p class="align">$40.00</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-products"><img src="images/categorie-3.jpg" >
                    <h1 class="align">Mexikodro</h1>
                    <p class="align">$40.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="align">Products On Sale!</h1>
        <h2 class="align">Under $20.00</h2>
        <div class="row">




            <div class="col-sale"> <img src="images/C0.jpg">
               <h3 class="align">Headphones!</h3>
               </div>


            <div class="col-sale"> <img src="images/C1.jpg">
               <h3 class="align">Speakers!</h3>
               </div>

            <div class="col-sale"> <img src="images/C2.jpg">
               <h3 class="align">Keyboards!</h3>
               </div>

                 <div class="col-sale"> <img src="" id="pics">
               <h3 class="align">Controllers!</h3>
               </div>







        </div>



    </div>





    <script>

        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);     // returns a random integer from 0 to 2
           document.getElementById("pics").src = "images/C"+randomIndex+".jpg";

    </script>





</body>
</html>
```

and here is my css

```
*{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

a:hover{ text-decoration:underline;}

.navbar{
    display:grid;
    min-height:100px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;


}

.logo{
    display:grid;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;

}

.links{
    display:grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
    grid-gap:20px;
    font-size:20px;

}

.header{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/30/20/41/banner-1363794_960_720.jpg");
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100vh;
    flex-direction:row;
    margin:auto;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
         justify-content:center;
             align-content:center;
    padding:40px;
    color:white;





}


.hero {

display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  wdith: auto;
  background-image: url("https://img.rawpixel.com/s3fs-private/rawpixel_images/website_content/rm233-eye-02.jpg?w=1300&dpr=1&fit=default&crop=default&q=80&vib=3&con=3&usm=15&bg=F4F4F3&ixlib=js-2.2.1&s=b625852b7057993e0983ec35ceb8e4b3");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin:auto;
  align-items: center;
  color:white;
  padding-top:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
    overflow: hidden;



}

.hero-title{
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15px;

}
button{

    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
      justify-content:center;
      font-size:10px;


}

button:hover{color:red;}


.products{
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.row{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-around;


}

.col-products{
    flex-basis:30%;
    min-width:250px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding-top:20px;

}
.col-products img {
    width:100%;
}

.col-products img:hover{
    opacity:0.5;
}

.wrapper{
    max-width:1080px;
    margin:auto;

}

.align{
    text-align:center;
}

.col-sale{
    flex-basis:25%;
    min-width:250px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding:10px;

}

.col-sale img{
    width:100%;

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated:), I am just starting to learn JavaScript

Comment: have you tried putting script in the head? Just place it there and test does it still have same behavior?

Comment: @WahabShah when I place the script in the head, now the behaviour of the corner happens on the top aswell

Comment: so there is some conflict with certain code in between. What do you mean when you said when you go below navbar it doesn't work?

Comment: @WahabShah so, if I was to post this line of code                                                       
    <div class="col-sale"> <img src="" id="pics"> which calls on my javascript function below any other code thats when it doesn't work

Comment: Okay try one thing, just in your js hard code the src link like `document.getElementById("pics").src = "images/C1.jpg";` .Like this and see if still works or doesn't

Comment: Ps: and try putting your code inside `window.onload function` to make sure the code is executed after DOM is loaded